# How to bind data from parent component to reusable component in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a sidebar as reusable component that use in `ng-template` inside blogComponent and blogDeatilComponent. 
how can i bind data from blog to sidebar?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bizgdk)

Answer (score 1):

you can pass data to your Directive by @Input() in angular, in your directive:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef, OnInit , Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ReusableService } from './reusable.service';

@Directive({
    selector: '[reusableOutlet]'
})
export class ReusableDirective implements OnInit {

   @Input()
    set reusableOutlet(passedValue: any) {
        console.log(passedValue);
    }

    constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private reusableService: ReusableService) {}

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.reusableService.attach(this.viewContainerRef);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
<ng-template [reusableOutlet]="data"></ng-template>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmjxxs).

Comment: how can i bind in sidebar component?

Comment: @MohammadJalili may you please explain more that what you really want to do, and bind what in sidebar?

Comment: i want bind some data like blog's category,tags and etc. i get this data from blog component and i want too keep this data when go to blog detail page in sidebar

Comment: do you understand?